# Which one is the correct use of "today..."?

Tags: word-usage

(A) Today is the day **when** I will eat that apple.

(B) Today is the day **where** I will eat that apple.

Which one is correct?

Comment: Where is a place, not a time. If today is understood to be a place along a time continuum, then where is correct. Context matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion the correct one will be " Today is the day when I will eat that apple"

Because "when" is using for time.
Also, remember that "where" is only using for places.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely 'when'. Today is a time, not a place.

Also you might consider changing the title of the question. The question is not about how to use 'today' ('today' is used the same in both sentences), but about when to use the relative adverbs 'when' and 'where'.